# What affects visibility of a question on google?

Tags: support

Question header more or less sums it up. If I had in mind that I wanted a question to be visible to a google search using particular keywords, would it be sufficient to just include those words in a question body? Is there anything on the SE end that affects this? Or is it purely up to the search engine?

Comment: I think you can pay google to put it on top as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE does some search engine optimization by including a relevant tag in the page title.

Otherwise, yes, just use the keywords in the post. The search engine does the rest.

Comment: Putting the relevant keywords in the title would be much more effective from a SEO point of view.